# Listening to device shake event on background mode

Tags: ios, swift, accelerometer, core-motion

I'm new to iOS development, with strong background in Android.

I know that Android gives developers much more control and power to do whatever they want, and it's pretty easy to listen to the accelerometer event if your app was closed a month ago.

I know that iOS gives a few background processing abilities, but the nature of motion events is to be handled via a view controller.

Is there any way to listen to motion event while the app is in background state?

Comment: Duplicate: [Receive accelerometer updates in background using CoreMotion framework](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21380806/2415822).  I cannot vote to close this question due to the bounty attached.

Comment: Indeed it is not possible, just an iOS restriction. You could create an app that constantly uses location services in the background and use that to allow your app to run in the background, then check for motion while checking for location, but your app wouldn't be allowed into the app store.

Comment: mmm maybe I'm wrong but is quite possible, I make it work adding to my "start" function runInBackground. 
example:

(void)start:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
[self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{

...
 [self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
...
}]

Answer (score 9):

According to Apple's [Background Execution Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html), listening to motion events in the background is not supported.